# The confusion with how V8 engine works

Tags: javascript, v8

I am new to JS and was learning how V8 engine works behind the scenes. Is it true that V8 generates bytecode rather than machine code. I mean, after ignition generates bytecode, then bytecode is analyzed by profiler for improvements and then that bytecode is analyzed and optimized by compiler(Turbofan), that is, Does TurboFan generate machine code out of bytecode or generate optimized bytecode?

Answer (score 1):

V8 developer here. Turbofan produces optimized machine code.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, ok two questions. Firstly, Am I right that ignition is needed because it helps to compile code faster and thanks to ignition final machine code will be compact and memory efficient? Secondly, is it true that profiler monitors ignition WHILE ignition is generating bytecode to find optimizations and only after bytecode is generated, compiler starts working and optimizing code. I really hope for your kind comments)))

Comment: Re 1, optimization of JavaScript requires type feedback collected during unoptimized execution; Ignition is one of several possible ways to do that. Re 2, no, bytecode generation is not monitored. The profiler monitors *executed* bytecode and eventually triggers optimized compilation for hot functions.

Comment: Re 1, ok I read in https://medium.com/@MQuy90/v8-engine-overview-7c965731ced4 that Ignition is needed since it generates bytecode which 25% to 50% of the size of JIT compiler previously generated. So, when compiler takes that bytecode and compiles it into machine code the size of code will be smaller RIght? Re 2, ok, after bytecode is generated by ignition then that bytecode is executed and profiler takes care of optimization analyses and then the analyses with the bytecode is given to compiler to output final optimized machine code. Right?

Comment: Re 1, the size of the bytecode does not affect the size of optimized code in any way. The numbers quoted in that post compared Ignition's bytecode to the unoptimized machine code produced by the non-optimizing compiler that Ignition replaced. Ignition is not "needed" per se; it's a better solution than what we had before. Re 2, the profiler only selects functions to optimize, the optimizing compiler does the optimizations. It doesn't analyze the bytecode, it builds its own IR from the bytecode and then analyzes/transforms that.

Comment: I had a look at that article you linked and found it pretty confusing. I think you'll probably get a better understanding if you read the articles we have on v8.dev/blog/.

Comment: Re 1 ))) my gosh please can you very briefly explain why need ignition since I understood ignition as something that helps to make our code compact and efficient for mobile phones to run, Re 2, so, the profiler only selects functions to optimize and then compiler optimize those selected functions. After optimizations done to selected functions by compiler then the compiler compiles the overall bytecode with optimizations into machine code Right?

Comment: please don't think I am bombarding you with questions it is just honour for me to ask questions from person who is directly involved in V8

Comment: please these are my last questions(((

Comment: @tmrk, please can you answer to my second question at least?

Comment: Yes, the compiler produces machine code in the end.